# Why am I getting the "refers to field which is not local to model" error while migrating the following models?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a database schema for a simple Visitor Management System where I am creating two models named Visitor and Host by extending the inbuilt User model in Django. The model `Appointment` is for mapping the relation between the Visitor and Host with their meeting time slot. However, I am getting the `'demoapp.Appointment.host_email' refers to field 'email' which is not local to model 'demoapp.Host'` error mentioned in the title when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`. Why am I getting this, how can I fix it and is there a better way to do it?

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
 
class Host(User):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Host"
        verbose_name_plural = "Hosts"
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[0-9]{10}')], unique=True, null=True)
 
class Visitor(User):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Visitor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Visitors"
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[0-9]{10}')], unique=True, null=True)
    purpose = models.CharField(verbose_name='Purpose of meeting', max_length=150, null=True)
 
class Appointment(models.Model):
    host_email = models.ForeignKey(Host, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Host Email')
    visitor_email = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Visitor Email')
    slot = models.DateField(verbose_name='Appointment Slot', default=timezone.now)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Booking Confirmed', default=False)
```

Comment: did you register your model in ```INSTALLED_APPS```?

Comment: yes he did. wouldn't get this error otherwise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you specifying `to_field` in your foreign key? I think you may be misusing it. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field). You probably just want to leave that option off, and let Django use the primary key (id) of `Host`.

If you *do* mean to use it, you need an `email` attribute of your model `Host`. That is what the error is telling you. You'll also need to make this unique if you're going to use it as the field for your `ForeignKey`.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
 
class Host(User):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Host"
        verbose_name_plural = "Hosts"
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[0-9]{10}')], unique=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)  # You're missing this
 
class Visitor(User):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Visitor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Visitors"
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[0-9]{10}')], unique=True, null=True)
    purpose = models.CharField(verbose_name='Purpose of meeting', max_length=150, null=True)
 
class Appointment(models.Model):
    host_email = models.ForeignKey(Host, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Host Email')
    visitor_email = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Visitor Email')
    slot = models.DateField(verbose_name='Appointment Slot', default=timezone.now)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Booking Confirmed', default=False)
```